# Why am I not able to process the JSON response?

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I am getting back some JSON, and need to display it on my page, however it won't seem to display!

Could someone please have a look and see if you can see where I am going wrong?

Code:

```
 $.ajax({ type: "GET",
    url: "URL GOES HERE - Cant give for obvious reasons :)",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    success: function (response) {
        var result = response.d;
        $.each(result, function (index, res) {
            $('#questions').val(res.q);

        });
    },
    error: function (msg) {

    }
});
```

JSON:

```
{
  "d": [
        {
            "id": "1002 ",
            "q": "What region is Auchentoshan whisky made in",
            "a1": "Highlands",
            "a2": "Speyside",
            "a3": "Lowlands"
        },
        {
            "id": "1042 ",
            "q": "Chase’s award winning vodka is made from...",
            "a1": "Grapes",
            "a2": "Rye",
            "a3": "Potatoes"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: So `console.log(response)` in success handler gives nothing?

Comment: what element on your page has an id of "questions"?

Comment: Why are you using `datatype : "jsonp"` instead of `"json"`?

Comment: json was not working, however jsonp is

Comment: You're changing the same element on each iteration, effectively setting it to the value of the last iteration.

Comment: It does not seem to even be going in the success section. However i am getting the JSON back?!

Comment: @adeneo even setting the textbox to just display all outside the each it does nto work

Comment: In your browser, press F12 to open the console. In your code inside the `each()` function add `console.log(res.q);` and see what comes up in the console. You should use the console to figure out what is returning and what is going on, just aimlessly trying stuff will just give you grief.

Comment: @thatuxguy you say "`json` was not working, however `jsonp` is." However, as evidenced by the fact that you're here asking what you're asking, `jsonp` is *not* working. You need a data type of `json` given the response you're sending. If something isn't working beyond that, other troubleshooting would be necessary. See my answer to for evidence that `json` is the correct data type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('#questions').val(res.q);
```

Depending on your what you're trying to set, you may need to use:

```
$('#questions').html(res.q);
```

Comment: And probably shouldn't be using an id, unless only showing one question at a time.

Comment: this is currently just testing to make sure thigns are coming back :)

Comment: i currently have a textbox with the id of questions just to make sure i can get something back :)

Answer (score 0):

With a `dataType` of `jsonp` the response is expected to be a JSON blob wrapped in a function call. As you're only returning JSON, you should use the `dataType` of `json`.

I've adjusted your example to work with the JSFiddle echo API. In the [first version](http://jsfiddle.net/gtYcr/), I used a `dataType` of `jsonp` as used in your code. As seen if you visit that link, it doesn't work. In the [edited version](http://jsfiddle.net/gtYcr/1/) I used a `dataType` of `json` and it works just fine.